# How to remove fringes around text using python and Opencv or PIL

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, document, watermark

I am working on a document watermarking and recovery project. My code works fine for embedding the watermark and then recovering it. It works great with digitally generated images that haven't been scaled or modified in any way. But, when I use scanned images or modified, The recovered portion is good enough to be read when not zoomed but not great. The problem is that the original images have fringes of colour around the text. Those chunks of colourful pixels cause a bad average to be stored. This average when use for recovery, cause the recovered text, signatures or any other artefacts to have bad colours. Below are some images representing the problem. On the left is the recovered portion while the right has untampered portion. The untampered portion shows how the original image had bad colours all around the text.

How do I remove that bad colouring or blocks?
Any ideas about removing them from the recovered part or the original image itself?

[image: Please check this image]

Comment: If you’re using jpeg format and have any control on the quality set it to as high quality (large file size) as possible. Or if you can avoid jpeg then all the better.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but any random use his supposed to be the generator of original image. So, no control over the quality of original image. Watermarked and recovered are saved as BMP for now.